# How to get data from Sub Site in App?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have created a web which is a sub web of the "Host Web"(In terms of App).

I want to get data from a list which is part of that sub web into my SharePoint hosted App.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can consider using REST, and you'll need to know some JavaScript/JQuery.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx

There's a section on working with list items, which will allow you to retrieve items in a list; you'll need to work with the url, and either the list title or GUID.